# why are the strings not equal?

Tags: c, string, palindrome

```
#include "usefunc.h"
#define MY_SIZE 256

int inpArr(char tmp[], int size) {
    size = -1;
    while(1) {
        size++;
        if((tmp[size] = getchar()) == '\n') break;
    }
    return size;
}

void revString(char tmp[], int size, char new[]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = size, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) new[j] = tmp[i];
}

void copy_forw(char tmp[], int size, char new[], int offset) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = offset, j = 0; i <= size; i++, j++) new[j] = tmp[i];
}

void copy_back(char tmp[], int size, char new[], int offset) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = size-offset, j = size; i > -1; i--, j--) new[j] = tmp[i];
}

void cut(char tmp[], int size, char new[]) {

}

int main () {
    char tmp[MY_SIZE] = {0x0}, rev[MY_SIZE] = {0x0}, new[MY_SIZE] = {0x0}, some[MY_SIZE-1];
    int size = inpArr(tmp, size);
    revString(tmp, size, rev);
    copy_forw(rev, size, new, 1); copy_back(tmp, size, some, 1);
    printf("|%s|\n|%s|\n", some, new);
    int is_palindrome = StringEqual(new, some);
    printf("%d\n", is_palindrome);
}
```

StringEqual is pretty much a function that just compares a char array character by character.
If I input the string `yay` it should be a palindrome, but doesn't appear to be. Why is this?

Comment: Try to debug it first, give us the error or the smallest piece of code possible. Don't use pastebin and don't include any tags in the title. That's what tags are for.

Comment: no error: just output is unexpected for "aya" or something

Comment: @tekknolagi: So you're getting aya instead of yay?

Comment: I agree with the_drow. Also, don't use the name `new` for variables, it is a reserved keyword in many languages and will cause you problems in the future.

Comment: okay thank you for the suggestion, but i'm using "aya" and it prints `|aya|` and `|aya|` but it returns 0

Comment: @MByD - `new` is a keyword in C++, not C. People don't "upgrade" their programs from one to the other. Should I avoid naming my variables or functions `import` because it's a keyword in Python?

Comment: @Chris - this is not an "upgrade" from C to C++,  isn't it an often used to merge C code with C++ code and compile it as C++ code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with the line that goes:

```
if((tmp[size] = getchar()) == '\n') break;
```

This line will always assign the character the user inputs into the array, even when the user inputs the `\n` character to indicate that they are done providing input.  So for example, when you enter "yay" and then a newline to indicate that you are done, your array looks like:

```
{'y', 'a', 'y', '\n'}
```

and the reverse of that array is:

```
{'\n', 'y', 'a', 'y'}
```

...which will obviously fail a palindrome check.  I would suggest revising your code as follows:

```
int inpArr(char tmp[], int size) {
    size = -1;
    while(1) {
        size++;
        if((tmp[size] = getchar()) == '\n') break;
    }
    tmp[size] = '\0';  //replace the newline with a null terminator
    return size;
}

void revString(char tmp[], int size, char new[]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = size - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) new[j] = tmp[i];
    new[size] = '\0';  //place a null terminator at the end of the reversed string
}
```

Comment: Arggh!! Was just getting ready to submit this answer when yours popped in. +1, and well played.

Comment: hmmm - what happens is it now prints (say i enter `yay`): `|yay|` and `|ya|` and `0`

Comment: @tekknolagi - You may also need to make some adjustments to your `copy_forw` and `copy_back` functions.  I didn't provided any revised code for them because I'm not sure what they are trying to do.  If you want to check for a palindrome, it seems to me like all you should need is `inpArray`, `revString`, and `StringEqual`.  What are the additional methods being used for?

Comment: the other ones were trying to remove newlines...huh okay.

Answer (score 1):

Look at line:

```
if((tmp[size] = getchar()) == '\n') break;
```

`'\n'` is always present at the end of the string. That's your problem.